# Java - Setting the BooleanProperty causes 'java.lang.StackOverflowError'

Tags: java, properties, boolean, listener, javafx-8

I'm not going to post all of the code, just parts that are associated with it. I am not really too familiar with creating my own listener, and this book hasn't covered this yet. Maybe I'm doing it wrong but you can review the code below and see for yourself. Basically when I change the value it keeps trying to set the value or something over and over again, I tried to trace it with a breakpoint to see if I could catch the problem but maybe I was missing something...Tracing the problem stopped at that specific line of code which set the BooleanProperty value and stayed there every time I moved it forward a line.

here is my Objects constructor and data field

```
private BooleanProperty endTurn;

/** Constructor */
public PlayerHand() {
    // Set the Data Field values
    super.playerCards = new ArrayList<>();
    this.chips = 100;
    this.lastBet = 0;
    this.endTurn = new SimpleBooleanProperty(this, "endTurn", false);
}
```

Here is the getter, setter, and property methods

```
/** Get whether the player has ended the turn */
public boolean getEndTurn() {
    return this.endTurn.get();
}

/** Set's the end of turn */
public void setEndTurn(boolean endTurn) {
    this.endTurn.setValue(endTurn);
}

/** Property getter method for ending the turn */
public BooleanProperty endTurnProperty() {
    return this.endTurn;
}
```

and here is the listener in the class that created the object

```
    // Set the binds for each player
    for (int i = 0; i < players - 1; i++) {
        alPlayerHand.get(i).endTurnProperty().addListener(e -> {
            progressTurn();
        });
    }
```

Edit: I forgot to add this line which is were the trace gets stuck

```
public void progressTurn() {
    // Have AI make their decisions and turn rules on and off
    if (alPlayerHand.get(playersTurn).getLastBet() == 0) {
        if (alPlayerHand.get(playersTurn).isLittleBlind() &&
                currentGameRound == 1) {
            alPlayerHand.get(playersTurn).setBet(littleBlind);
            lastPlayer = "Little Blind";
        } else if (alPlayerHand.get(playersTurn).isBigBlind() &&
                currentGameRound == 1) {
            alPlayerHand.get(playersTurn).setBet(bigBlind);
            lastPlayer = "Big Blind";
        } else if (alPlayerHand.get(playersTurn).isAI()) {
            alPlayerHand.get(playersTurn).decide();
            lastPlayer = alPlayerHand.get(playersTurn).getLastMove();
        }
    }
    // Add the last bet to the pot
    pot += alPlayerHand.get(playersTurn).getLastBet();
    alPlayerHand.get(playersTurn).setBet(0);

    if ((playersTurn + 1) <= players - 1 &&
        alPlayerHand.get(playersTurn).isAI()) {
        playersTurn++;
    } else if ((playersTurn + 1) > players - 1 &&
        alPlayerHand.get(playersTurn).isAI())
        playersTurn = 0;

    endTurn(); // Debug stops here and stays here
}
```

Edit: Again forgot code

```
/** End the current players turn */
public void endTurn() {
    // End Players turn
    if (alPlayerHand.get(playersTurn).getEndTurn()) {
        alPlayerHand.get(playersTurn).setEndTurn(false);
    } else
        alPlayerHand.get(playersTurn).setEndTurn(true);
}
```

Finally here is the error - Most has been removed because it just repeats itself

```
Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.StackOverflowError
at javafx.beans.property.BooleanPropertyBase.markInvalid(BooleanPropertyBase.java:109)
at javafx.beans.property.BooleanPropertyBase.set(BooleanPropertyBase.java:143)
at javafx.beans.property.BooleanProperty.setValue(BooleanProperty.java:77)
at Casino_Poker.PlayerHand.setEndTurn(PlayerHand.java:188)
at Casino_Poker.Main.endTurn(Main.java:1043)
at Casino_Poker.Main.progressTurn(Main.java:1014)
at Casino_Poker.Main.lambda$TexasHoldEm$16(Main.java:972)
at Casino_Poker.Main$$Lambda$13/477174400.invalidated(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javafx.binding.ExpressionHelper$SingleInvalidation.fireValueChangedEvent(ExpressionHelper.java:135)
at com.sun.javafx.binding.ExpressionHelper.fireValueChangedEvent(ExpressionHelper.java:80)
at javafx.beans.property.BooleanPropertyBase.fireValueChangedEvent(BooleanPropertyBase.java:103)
at javafx.beans.property.BooleanPropertyBase.markInvalid(BooleanPropertyBase.java:110)
at javafx.beans.property.BooleanPropertyBase.set(BooleanPropertyBase.java:143)
at javafx.beans.property.BooleanProperty.setValue(BooleanProperty.java:77)
at Casino_Poker.PlayerHand.setEndTurn(PlayerHand.java:188)
at Casino_Poker.Main.endTurn(Main.java:1041)
at Casino_Poker.Main.progressTurn(Main.java:1014)
at Casino_Poker.Main.lambda$TexasHoldEm$16(Main.java:972)
at Casino_Poker.Main$$Lambda$13/477174400.invalidated(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javafx.binding.ExpressionHelper$SingleInvalidation.fireValueChangedEvent(ExpressionHelper.java:135)
at com.sun.javafx.binding.ExpressionHelper.fireValueChangedEvent(ExpressionHelper.java:80)
at javafx.beans.property.BooleanPropertyBase.fireValueChangedEvent(BooleanPropertyBase.java:103)
at javafx.beans.property.BooleanPropertyBase.markInvalid(BooleanPropertyBase.java:110)
at javafx.beans.property.BooleanPropertyBase.set(BooleanPropertyBase.java:143)
at javafx.beans.property.BooleanProperty.setValue(BooleanProperty.java:77)
at Casino_Poker.PlayerHand.setEndTurn(PlayerHand.java:188)
at Casino_Poker.Main.endTurn(Main.java:1043)
at Casino_Poker.Main.progressTurn(Main.java:1014)
at Casino_Poker.Main.lambda$TexasHoldEm$16(Main.java:972)
at Casino_Poker.Main$$Lambda$13/477174400.invalidated(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javafx.binding.ExpressionHelper$SingleInvalidation.fireValueChangedEvent(ExpressionHelper.java:135)
at com.sun.javafx.binding.ExpressionHelper.fireValueChangedEvent(ExpressionHelper.java:80)
at javafx.beans.property.BooleanPropertyBase.fireValueChangedEvent(BooleanPropertyBase.java:103)
at javafx.beans.property.BooleanPropertyBase.markInvalid(BooleanPropertyBase.java:110)
at javafx.beans.property.BooleanPropertyBase.set(BooleanPropertyBase.java:143)
at javafx.beans.property.BooleanProperty.setValue(BooleanProperty.java:77)
at Casino_Poker.PlayerHand.setEndTurn(PlayerHand.java:188)
at Casino_Poker.Main.endTurn(Main.java:1043)
at Casino_Poker.Main.progressTurn(Main.java:1014)
at Casino_Poker.Main.lambda$TexasHoldEm$16(Main.java:972)
at Casino_Poker.Main$$Lambda$13/477174400.invalidated(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javafx.binding.ExpressionHelper$SingleInvalidation.fireValueChangedEvent(ExpressionHelper.java:135)
at com.sun.javafx.binding.ExpressionHelper.fireValueChangedEvent(ExpressionHelper.java:80)
at javafx.beans.property.BooleanPropertyBase.fireValueChangedEvent(BooleanPropertyBase.java:103)
at javafx.beans.property.BooleanPropertyBase.markInvalid(BooleanPropertyBase.java:110)
at javafx.beans.property.BooleanPropertyBase.set(BooleanPropertyBase.java:143)
at javafx.beans.property.BooleanProperty.setValue(BooleanProperty.java:77)
at Casino_Poker.PlayerHand.setEndTurn(PlayerHand.java:188)
at Casino_Poker.Main.endTurn(Main.java:1041)
at Casino_Poker.Main.progressTurn(Main.java:1014)
at Casino_Poker.Main.lambda$TexasHoldEm$16(Main.java:972)
at Casino_Poker.Main$$Lambda$13/477174400.invalidated(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javafx.binding.ExpressionHelper$SingleInvalidation.fireValueChangedEvent(ExpressionHelper.java:135)
at com.sun.javafx.binding.ExpressionHelper.fireValueChangedEvent(ExpressionHelper.java:80)
at javafx.beans.property.BooleanPropertyBase.fireValueChangedEvent(BooleanPropertyBase.java:103)
at javafx.beans.property.BooleanPropertyBase.markInvalid(BooleanPropertyBase.java:110)
at javafx.beans.property.BooleanPropertyBase.set(BooleanPropertyBase.java:143)
at javafx.beans.property.BooleanProperty.setValue(BooleanProperty.java:77)
at Casino_Poker.PlayerHand.setEndTurn(PlayerHand.java:188)
at Casino_Poker.Main.endTurn(Main.java:1043)
at Casino_Poker.Main.progressTurn(Main.java:1014)
at Casino_Poker.Main.lambda$TexasHoldEm$16(Main.java:972)
at Casino_Poker.Main$$Lambda$13/477174400.invalidated(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javafx.binding.ExpressionHelper$SingleInvalidation.fireValueChangedEvent(ExpressionHelper.java:135)
at com.sun.javafx.binding.ExpressionHelper.fireValueChangedEvent(ExpressionHelper.java:80)
at javafx.beans.property.BooleanPropertyBase.fireValueChangedEvent(BooleanPropertyBase.java:103)
at javafx.beans.property.BooleanPropertyBase.markInvalid(BooleanPropertyBase.java:110)
at javafx.beans.property.BooleanPropertyBase.set(BooleanPropertyBase.java:143)
at javafx.beans.property.BooleanProperty.setValue(BooleanProperty.java:77)
at Casino_Poker.PlayerHand.setEndTurn(PlayerHand.java:188)
at Casino_Poker.Main.endTurn(Main.java:1041)
at Casino_Poker.Main.progressTurn(Main.java:1014)
at Casino_Poker.Main.lambda$TexasHoldEm$16(Main.java:972)
at Casino_Poker.Main$$Lambda$13/477174400.invalidated(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javafx.binding.ExpressionHelper$SingleInvalidation.fireValueChangedEvent(ExpressionHelper.java:135)
at com.sun.javafx.binding.ExpressionHelper.fireValueChangedEvent(ExpressionHelper.java:80)
at javafx.beans.property.BooleanPropertyBase.fireValueChangedEvent(BooleanPropertyBase.java:103)
at javafx.beans.property.BooleanPropertyBase.markInvalid(BooleanPropertyBase.java:110)
at javafx.beans.property.BooleanPropertyBase.set(BooleanPropertyBase.java:143)
at javafx.beans.property.BooleanProperty.setValue(BooleanProperty.java:77)
at Casino_Poker.PlayerHand.setEndTurn(PlayerHand.java:188)
at Casino_Poker.Main.endTurn(Main.java:1043)
at Casino_Poker.Main.progressTurn(Main.java:1014)
at Casino_Poker.Main.lambda$TexasHoldEm$16(Main.java:972)
at Casino_Poker.Main$$Lambda$13/477174400.invalidated(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javafx.binding.ExpressionHelper$SingleInvalidation.fireValueChangedEvent(ExpressionHelper.java:135)
at com.sun.javafx.binding.ExpressionHelper.fireValueChangedEvent(ExpressionHelper.java:80)
at javafx.beans.property.BooleanPropertyBase.fireValueChangedEvent(BooleanPropertyBase.java:103)
at javafx.beans.property.BooleanPropertyBase.markInvalid(BooleanPropertyBase.java:110)
at javafx.beans.property.BooleanPropertyBase.set(BooleanPropertyBase.java:143)
at javafx.beans.property.BooleanProperty.setValue(BooleanProperty.java:77)
at Casino_Poker.PlayerHand.setEndTurn(PlayerHand.java:188)
at Casino_Poker.Main.endTurn(Main.java:1041)
at Casino_Poker.Main.progressTurn(Main.java:1014)
at Casino_Poker.Main.lambda$TexasHoldEm$16(Main.java:972)
at Casino_Poker.Main$$Lambda$13/477174400.invalidated(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javafx.binding.ExpressionHelper$SingleInvalidation.fireValueChangedEvent(ExpressionHelper.java:135)
at com.sun.javafx.binding.ExpressionHelper.fireValueChangedEvent(ExpressionHelper.java:80)
at javafx.beans.property.BooleanPropertyBase.fireValueChangedEvent(BooleanPropertyBase.java:103)
at javafx.beans.property.BooleanPropertyBase.markInvalid(BooleanPropertyBase.java:110)
at javafx.beans.property.BooleanPropertyBase.set(BooleanPropertyBase.java:143)
at javafx.beans.property.BooleanProperty.setValue(BooleanProperty.java:77)
at Casino_Poker.PlayerHand.setEndTurn(PlayerHand.java:188)
at Casino_Poker.Main.endTurn(Main.java:1043)
at Casino_Poker.Main.progressTurn(Main.java:1014)
at Casino_Poker.Main.lambda$TexasHoldEm$16(Main.java:972)
at Casino_Poker.Main$$Lambda$13/477174400.invalidated(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javafx.binding.ExpressionHelper$SingleInvalidation.fireValueChangedEvent(ExpressionHelper.java:135)
at com.sun.javafx.binding.ExpressionHelper.fireValueChangedEvent(ExpressionHelper.java:80)
at javafx.beans.property.BooleanPropertyBase.fireValueChangedEvent(BooleanPropertyBase.java:103)
at javafx.beans.property.BooleanPropertyBase.markInvalid(BooleanPropertyBase.java:110)
at javafx.beans.property.BooleanPropertyBase.set(BooleanPropertyBase.java:143)
at javafx.beans.property.BooleanProperty.setValue(BooleanProperty.java:77)
at Casino_Poker.PlayerHand.setEndTurn(PlayerHand.java:188)
at Casino_Poker.Main.endTurn(Main.java:1043)
at Casino_Poker.Main.progressTurn(Main.java:1014)
at Casino_Poker.Main.lambda$TexasHoldEm$16(Main.java:972)
at Casino_Poker.Main$$Lambda$13/477174400.invalidated(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javafx.binding.ExpressionHelper$SingleInvalidation.fireValueChangedEvent(ExpressionHelper.java:135)
at com.sun.javafx.binding.ExpressionHelper.fireValueChangedEvent(ExpressionHelper.java:80)
at javafx.beans.property.BooleanPropertyBase.fireValueChangedEvent(BooleanPropertyBase.java:103)
at javafx.beans.property.BooleanPropertyBase.markInvalid(BooleanPropertyBase.java:110)
```

I would really appreciate any advice as to what I'm doing wrong, the book only covered the creation of binding properties so far...but never covered the inner workings, only how the method's were setup without the statements within them visible.

Basically I am wanting the players to make their move, if the player is AI controlled then the Computer makes the decision and at the end of either it sets the endTurn value which will then cause the listener to call on the progressTurn method and the cycle continues

Comment: Well presumably you've got something listening to when `endTurn` changes... and then setting it. (To be honest, `endTurn` doesn't really sound like a property to me, but that's a different matter...)

Comment: Yeah, sorry about that I forgot some code I placed the setter for the end of the turn on it's own so I could save a few lines of code since I use it in different places, like when the player presses the button it performs it's own separate command, but I may change that later...I'm basically setting everything up and then I'm going to go back over it and clean up the code.

Comment: Well what you've *really* failed to show is the code which hooks into the "endTurn has changed!" event - which apparently then calls `processTurn`, which in itself changes `endTurn`, etc. Do you see why that causes a problem?

Comment: By the way, please excuse the code if it seems a bit messy this is my first attempt at a real project in java and I am still very new to the event-driven programming concept

Comment: Understood. I suspect you won't be able to get a real *answer* here... it's mostly a matter of understanding why you're in the current pickle you are. (And yes, event-driven programming can be a pain... or it can be lovely.)

Comment: Alright, let me try to clear it up a bit....when the player starts a new game, it creates the player objects it then creates listeners to the 'public BooleanProperty endTurnProperty() {' in the playerhand object so that it calls on progressTurn...I don't have it setup yet but when the game is run it will basically call upon progressTurn until it's a non-AI player's turn, thereafter when the player selects an option such as betting, checking, calling, or folding, the game will call upon the endTurn method setting the end of the turn and setting off the listener...the cycle continues

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/59831/discussion-between-john-conner-and-jon-skeet).

Comment: I don't have time to chat at the moment, I'm afraid. Maybe someone else will be able to help.

Comment: Unfortunately, I am not seeing the issue in the code provided. However, in most of my experience, anytime I received a StackOverFlow error was from getter method calling itself. However, I'm sure the issue can be elsewhere if that is not the case.

Comment: at Casino_Poker.PlayerHand.setEndTurn(PlayerHand.java:188)
at Casino_Poker.Main.endTurn(Main.java:1041)
at Casino_Poker.Main.progressTurn(Main.java:1014)
at Casino_Poker.Main.lambda$TexasHoldEm$16(Main.java:972)
at Casino_Poker.Main$$Lambda$13/477174400.invalidated(Unknown Source) <- Excuse me copying part of the stack trace, but considering the stack trace repeats itself in this area of your program the problem probably lies within there.

Comment: If you'd liked me to help further, feel free to ask. I'll try my best.

Comment: @Frizinator when i called upon the getter for the boolean property in the if statement, i am assuming that it was setting off my listener so what i did was replace it with 'if (playersTurn % 2 == 0)'

Comment: @Frizinator i think so im still not sure exactly but it did have to do with the getter because when i stopped using the getter to test the value for true it started working again

Answer (score 0):

When i called upon the getter for the boolean property in the if statement of the endTurn() method, i am assuming that it was setting off my listener so what i did was replace it with 'if (playersTurn % 2 == 0)'